# uitabelview custom button tag issue

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am creating a custom button in my uitable and giving the button a tag number as shown in code below.

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    //NSLog(@"Inside cellForRowAtIndexPath");

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    // Try to retrieve from the table view a now-unused cell with the given identifier.
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // If no cell is available, create a new one using the given identifier.
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        // Use the default cell style.
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [button addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(selectPicOnBtnTouch:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [button setTitle:@"btn1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(6.0f, 0.0f, 97.0f, 110.0f);
        button.tag = (indexPath.row)+100;
        [cell addSubview:button];

        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sample_pic.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
    else
    {
        //NSLog(@"went here 2");
        button = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:((indexPath.row)+100)];
    }

    //Get an arrow next to the name
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    return cell;

}

- (IBAction) selectPicOnBtnTouch:(id)sender
{
    button = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSLog(@"[button tag]: %d ...", [button tag]); 
}
```

If I have a table with 10 rows and when I touch buttons in rows 1-5 I get the following in my log

```
[button tag]: 100 ...
[button tag]: 101 ...
[button tag]: 102 ...
[button tag]: 103 ...
[button tag]: 104 ...
```

This is fine. The problem is that when I touch row 6-10 I am expecting 105 - 109 tags but what I get back is same tag numbers starting over

```
[button tag]: 100 ...
[button tag]: 101 ...
[button tag]: 102 ...
[button tag]: 103 ...
[button tag]: 104 ...
```

The reason I want to keep the tag numbers unique (and not repeating) is so that I know which button corresponds to what row. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before You follow my Answer i wnat to tell you that following code is bad for memory management because it will create new cell for each rows of `UITableView`, so be careful for it.

But it is better to use, When `UITableView` Have Limited rows *(about 50-100 may be )* then following code is helpful in your case, use it if is it suitable for you.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

         /// Put your code here
     }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: +1 for comments about memory management. Not a lot of users tell you when its bad for memory management.

Comment: Yeah not a lot of users understand the reusable cells stuff and they think they can create as many cells as they like without it causing an issue.

Comment: I changed the code (see my post again) and it still made no difference. what did I miss?

Comment: @SamBudda- just follow my Edited answer and  change your code :)

Comment: @iPatel - Thank you it works. I assume it will blow up if there are more than 100+ rows?

Comment: @SamBudda- good i glad to help you, nothing more just it is bad for memory management, no other issue is created.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't set the button tag inside the if block where you create the cell, because cells will be reused** and you are not updating the tag in the scenario when the cell is reused.

> **EDIT :**
>   For the first 5 cells, `if` block is being executed and new cells are
>   being created. 6th cell onwards the cells are being reused and hence
>   count is not incremened.

Call your

```
button.tag = (indexPath.row)+100;
```

below your `if (cell == nil)` block, like this:

```
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        //...

    }
    else
    {
      ///...
        button = (UIButton*)[[cell subviews] lastObject]; //this assumes your button is the last view in the subview array (double check)
    }
    button.tag = (indexPath.row)+100;
```

Comment: I just did and it made no difference. Still counts from 100-104 and then over

Comment: when the cell is reused - is button nil? If so, you need to go into the cell and get your button subview manually and update the tag on it

Answer (score 0):

You need to do smth like that:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.rNewsCell = [self.tabelView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:allNewsCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (self.news.count != 0)
    {
        if(indexPath.row <[self.news count])
        {
            RNewsModel *news = (self.news)[indexPath.row];
            self.rNewsCell.newsImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
            self.rNewsCell.newsName.text = news.newsNameModel;
            self.rNewsCell.newsData.text = news.newsDataModel;
            self.rNewsCell.newsWatches.text = news.newsWatchesModel;
            self.rNewsCell.newsAddress.text = news.newsAddressModel;
            self.rNewsCell.newsTime.text = news.newsTimeModel;
            self.rNewsCell.playFrame.image =  [UIImage imageNamed: news.newsPlayImage];
            self.rNewsCell.playButton.tag = indexPath.row;
            self.rNewsCell.showOnMap.tag = indexPath.row;

            self.rNewsCell.rightUtilityButtons = [self rightButtons];
            self.rNewsCell.delegate = self;
        }
    }
    return self.rNewsCell;
}
```

and after that catch the button actions:

```
- (IBAction)showNewsOnTheMap:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button=(UIButton *) sender;
    self.showNewsOnMap = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:button.tag inSection:0];
    RNewsModel *news = (self.news)[self.showNewsOnMap.row];
    NSLog(@"didSelect NEWSOnMap = %@",news.newsIDModel);
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:SegueShowNewsOnTheMap sender:self];
}
```